# Quick Question - Complex roots of polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I was asked to find solutions to $z^3 = 1$ and give my answer in Cartesian form.

I got $1, -1/2 \pm i\sqrt{3}/2$

(b) Hence solve the equation $(z+i)^3 = (2z-i)^3$

Little help on this one? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ Jackie Ao: If you are new, just want to tell you that you, as the original poster of this question,  have the ability to accept an answer which you found useful.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. Write your last equation as
$$
\left(\frac{z+i}{2z-i}\right)^3=1 \qquad (2z-i \neq0)
$$ and solve $\dfrac{z+i}{2z-i}$ equals each of the preceding solutions (solutions to a)).